# Does TypeScript allow an enum to be assigned to an interface's object key?

Tags: typescript, enums

###### I would like to know if it is possible to assign an `enum` as a key to an object in an interface?

I wrote the snippet bellow to test if is (or isn't) possible.

```
    export enum colorsEnum{
    red,blue,green
    }
    
    export interface colorsInterface{
    [colorsEnum.red]:boolean,
    [colorsEnum.blue]:boolean,
    [colorsEnum.green]:boolean
    }
```

However, When I run the snippet, an error occurs that prints the following message:

###### `A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.`

I'm doing it wrong, or is it simply just not possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To define an interface, the member names must be supplied not computed.

```
export interface colorsInterface {
    red: boolean;
    blue: boolean;
    green: boolean;
}
```

If you are worried about keeping the enum and the interface in sync you could use the following:

```
export interface colorsInterface {
    [color: number]: boolean;
}

var example: colorsInterface = {};
example[colorsEnum.red] = true;
example[colorsEnum.blue] = false;
example[colorsEnum.green] = true;
```

TypeScript is perfectly happy for you to pass the enum as the index and a rename-refactor would then keep everything together if you decided to rename `red`, for example.

Comment: This is ok but what if we would like to restrict key values (in the signature) down to the available keys of the enum rather than a color:number. The [color: key in colorsEnum] does exactly this but requires you to provide all enum keys when you create a new object of this interface... So in my case I need even stronger type checking but for a partial of the enums keys. For now, to support my use case I just falled back to using primitives in my signature :(

Answer (score 121):

You can try with type:

```
export enum colorsEnum{
    red, blue, green
}

export type colorsInterface = {
    [key in colorsEnum]: boolean;
};

let example: colorsInterface = {
    [colorsEnum.red]: true,
    [colorsEnum.blue]: false,
    [colorsEnum.green]: true
};
```

Or if you do not want to use all keys: add a ?

```
export type colorsInterface = {
    [key in colorsEnum]?: boolean;
};

let example: colorsInterface = {
    [colorsEnum.red]: true,
    [colorsEnum.blue]: false
};
```

Comment: wow, this even works with string enums `export enum ColorsEnum{
    red = "red",
    blue = "blue",
    green = "green",
}`

Comment: This is essentially what the typescript `Record` utility type does for you.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This is just the solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 40):

OK, the key idea is to convert the Enum to the correct Type and to extends the Interface with it:
[You can check it out in live code here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgUSag3gWAFAyEwDWcAngIwwC8MARAG4CGANonBXQDT5EnkAmGvWZs4A7ryKkyAZmGNW7WZLwBffFDIAHOOkwBpchGEyQAMxhbdF-SgDcmnXowojZAGIBLOCwAmJrRYANoyMF5gdsjuEAC6AFwARiAgLHBMYBp4%20BFQcABO5kzAegCSrshoAB55YH5wfvA1CAFR7t6%20rbgERO7VFEkpaRmOPYR9VQLx0PkRAOajWfgA9MswACpw0OFQ%20KCQsAgopQcZJfEw5ZjVtfWNQVKE%20Gr2QA)

```
const enum Enum {
    key1 = "value1",
    key2 = "value2",
    key3 = "value3",
}
type EnumKeys = keyof typeof Enum;
type EnumKeyFields = {[key in EnumKeys]:boolean}

interface IEnumExtended extends EnumKeyFields {
    KeyEx1:boolean;
    KeyEx2:string;
}

// Test it
const enumInstance: IEnumExtended = {

};
```

when you inside the `enumInstance` you will get autocomplete for the Enum keys and not the values.

Comment: marvellous, I was looking for the same. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: what you earn from this line "type EnumKeys = keyof typeof Enum;
" ?

Comment: hi @yehonatanyehezkel, I earn Order and I notice the TS compiler working better when I create the "type". when doing `{[key in keyof typeof Enum]:boolean}` the compiler complains and it not so understandable when the code is not split to 2 lines. 

plus, I want to use the Keys and not the Values. The values can be explanation of the keys.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to have one enum for booleans and another for strings and combine them into a single field list type? Or perhaps specify the type as the value?

Comment: You can set type per Enum keys. and yes, you can `extends` multiple EnumKeyFields types as you want to the interface, each with other type, just make sure the keys are different.

Answer (score 24):

A simple solution using the native `Record<Keys, Type>` utility. ([Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype))

```js
export enum Colors {
    RED = 'red',
    GREEN = 'green',
    BLUE = 'blue'
}

export type ColorInterface = Record<Colors, boolean>
```

This type translates to:

```js
// translates to:

export type ColorInterface = {
    red: boolean;
    green: boolean;
    blue: boolean;
}
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: You *must* to define an `enum` key and map the values accordingly to them, else, you'll get a type / interface that uses an enum's `index` like the following:

```js
export enum Colors {
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue'
}

export type ColorInterface = Record<Colors, boolean>

// translates to:

export type ColorInterface = {
    0: boolean;
    1: boolean;
    2: boolean;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also define the Colors using `type` alias if you don't want to explicitly define the enum keys or if you have just a few keys to use, this will also translate properly to what you need:

```js
export type Colors = 'red' | 'green' | 'blue'

// will also translate to:

export type ColorInterface = {
    red: boolean;
    green: boolean;
    blue: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Easiest solution here!

Answer (score 12):

This worked for us:

```
type DictionaryFromEnum = {
  [key in keyof typeof SomeEnum]?: string
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not to keep it as simple as it should be:

```
export enum Color {
    Red = 'red',
    Blue = 'blue',
    Green = 'green'
}

export interface IColors{
    [Color.Red]: boolean,
    [Color.Blue]: boolean,
    [Color.Green]: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are searching for [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

> **Note**: Requires [*TypeScript ^4.1*](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2583).

Example:

```js
enum Color {
  red,
  blue,
  green,
}

// Define valid colors
// type TColor = 'red' | 'blue' | 'green';
type TColor = keyof typeof Color;

// Define object structure, with `color` as prefix for each `TColor`
type TWithColorCode = {
  [colorKey in TColor as `color${Capitalize<string & colorKey>}`]: string;
};

const a: TWithColorCode = {
  // All properties will be required
  colorGreen: '#00FF00',
  colorBlue: '#0000FF',
  colorRed: '#FF0000',
};

// Extending an `interface`:

export interface ICarRGB extends TWithColorCode {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // Optional property
  createdAt?: Date;
}

const b: ICarRGB = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Foo',
  colorGreen: '#00FF00',
  colorBlue: '#0000FF',
  colorRed: '#FF0000',
};
```