# Can I constrain an objects keys to an enums values using typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript, enums, typescript-generics

Essentially, I want a way to ensure that an options argument has keys which are the values of a specific enum:

```
//enum Mode { Foo, Bar };
interface Mode { Foo: number, Bar: number }

interface View { 
    text: string;
};

class FooView implements View {
    text = 'foo';
 }

class BarView implements View { 
    text = 'bar';
}

function initialize(options: { mode: {[P in keyof Mode]?: View} }) {
    let mode: View = options.mode.Foo;
}

initialize({ mode: { Bar: new FooView() } });
```

It works perfectly if I use an interface/class instead of enum, but this is truly an enum (conceptually)...

See [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2Fenum%20Mode%20%7B%20Foo%2C%20Bar%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20Mode%20%7B%20Foo%3A%20number%2C%20Bar%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20View%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FooView%20implements%20View%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%20%3D%20%27foo%27%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BarView%20implements%20View%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%20%3D%20%27bar%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initialize(options%3A%20%7B%20mode%3A%20%7B%5BP%20in%20keyof%20Mode%5D%3F%3A%20View%7D%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mode%3A%20View%20%3D%20options.mode.Foo%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainitialize(%7B%20mode%3A%20%7B%20Bar%3A%20new%20FooView()%20%7D%20%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys have to be either strings or numbers. You can kind of do this, but you have to use the bracket syntax and set your object's key as a number:

```
enum Mode { Foo, Bar };

function initialize(options: { mode: {[key:number]: View} }) {
    let mode: View = options.mode[Mode.Foo];
}

initialize({ mode: { [Mode.Bar]: new FooView() } });
```

The idea for this answer comes from [Sohnee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/sohnee)'s [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703832/215552).

Obviously the caveat here is that someone could just as easily do something like

```
initialize({ mode: { [999]: new FooView() } });
```

Less than optimal. The best you could do there is throw an error at run time if the value is not a valid Mode:

```
if (!Object.keys(options.mode).every((key) => key in Mode)) {
    throw new Error("Nice try");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines...  Definitely _less than optimal_.  Thanks for the info!