# What is the Record type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

What does `Record<K, T>` mean in Typescript?

Typescript 2.1 introduced the `Record` type, describing it in an example:

> ```
> // For every properties K of type T, transform it to U
> function mapObject<K extends string, T, U>(obj: Record<K, T>, f: (x: T) => U): Record<K, U>
> ```

see [Typescript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick)

And the [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) page mentions `Record` under the Mapped Types heading alongside `Readonly`, `Partial`, and `Pick`, in what appears to be its definition:

> ```
> type Record<K extends string, T> = {
>     [P in K]: T;
> }
> ```

> Readonly, Partial and Pick are homomorphic whereas Record is not. One clue that Record is not homomorphic is that it doesn’t take an input type to copy properties from:
>
> ```
> type ThreeStringProps = Record<'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3', string>
> ```

And that's it. Besides the above quotes, there is no other mention of `Record` on [typescriptlang.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://www.typescriptlang.org/+record&filter=0&biw=1372&bih=835).

### Questions

1. Can someone give a simple definition of what `Record` is?
2. Is `Record<K,T>` merely a way of saying "all properties on this object will have type `T`"? Probably not *all* properties, since `K` has some purpose...
3. Does the `K` generic forbid additional keys on the object that are not `K`, or does it allow them and just indicate that their properties are not transformed to `T`?
4. With the given example:

   ```
   type ThreeStringProps = Record<'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3', string>
   ```

   Is it exactly the same as this?:

   ```
   type ThreeStringProps = {prop1: string, prop2: string, prop3: string}
   ```

Comment: The answer to 4. is pretty much "yes", so that should probably answer your other questions.

Comment: At the moment of writing the docs page regarding Record is been deprecated and in the new one there is not even mention to those types

Comment: @CarmineTambascia do you have a link? The old _documentation site_ is deprecated but I don't see anything about Record being deprecated.

Comment: @Matthias I mean the same thing as you, not that Record is deprecated. It isn't mentioned anymore, as long I can see.

Comment: It is now listed in the Utility Types section: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Answer (score 645, accepted):

> 1. Can someone give a simple definition of what `Record` is?

A `Record<K, T>` is an object type whose property keys are `K` and whose property values are `T`.  That is, `keyof Record<K, T>` is equivalent to `K`, and `Record<K, T>[K]` is (basically) equivalent to `T`.

> 2. Is `Record<K,T>` merely a way of saying "all properties on this object will have type `T`"? Probably not all objects, since `K` has some purpose...

As you note, `K` has a purpose... to limit the property keys to particular values.  If you want to accept all possible string-valued keys, you could do something like `Record<string, T>`, but the idiomatic way of doing that is to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like `{ [k: string]: T }`.

> 3. Does the `K` generic forbid additional keys on the object that are not `K`, or does it allow them and just indicate that their properties are not transformed to `T`?

It doesn't exactly "forbid" additional keys: after all, a value is generally allowed to have properties not explicitly mentioned in its type... but it wouldn't recognize that such properties exist:

```
declare const x: Record<"a", string>;
x.b; // error, Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Record<"a", string>'
```

and it would treat them as [excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) which are sometimes rejected:

```
declare function acceptR(x: Record<"a", string>): void;
acceptR({a: "hey", b: "you"}); // error, Object literal may only specify known properties
```

and sometimes accepted:

```
const y = {a: "hey", b: "you"};
acceptR(y); // okay
```

> 4. With the given example:
>
>    ```
>     type ThreeStringProps = Record<'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3', string>
>    ```
>
>    Is it exactly the same as this?:
>
>    ```
>     type ThreeStringProps = {prop1: string, prop2: string, prop3: string}
>    ```

Yes!

Comment: Very much learned and a question why "the idiomatic way of doing that is to use an index signature" not a Record one ? I don't find any related information about this "idiomatic way".

Comment: You can use `Record<string, V>` to mean `{[x: string]: V}` if you want; I've probably even done this myself.   The index signature version is more direct:  they are the same type, but the former is a type alias of a mapped type which evaluates to an index signature, while the latter is just the index signature directly.  All else being equal, I'd recommend the latter.  Similarly I wouldn't use `Record<"a", string>` in place of `{a: string}` unless there were some other compelling contextual reason do to so.

Comment: "_All else being equal, I'd recommend the latter._" Why is that? My pre-Typescript self agrees, but I know the former will be more, um, self-commenting for people coming from the C# side, for instance, and no worse for JavaScript-to-Typescripters. Are you just interested in skipping the transpilation step for those constructs?

Comment: Just my opinion: the behavior of `Record<string, V>` only makes sense if you already know how index signatures work in TypeScript. E.g., given `x: Record<string, string>`, `x.foo` will apparently be a `string` at compile time, but in actuality is likely to be `string | undefined`. This is a gap in how `--strictNullChecks` works (see [#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778)). I'd rather have newcomers deal with `{[x: string]: V}` directly instead of expecting them to follow the chain from `Record<string, V>` through `{[P in string]: V}` to the index signature behavior.

Comment: I wanted to point out that logically a type can be defined as a set of all values contained within the type. given this interpretation I think Record<string, V> is reasonable as an abstraction to simplify the code instead of laying out all possible values. It is similar to the example in the utility types documentation: Record<T, V> where type T = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'. Never doing Record<'a', string> is not a good counter example, because it does not follow the same pattern. It also does not add to reuse or simplify the code through abstraction as the other examples do.

Comment: Can Record be used as C# dictionaries? Do Records have add(), remove() methods?

Comment: @KishanVaishnav no, it's just a plain object type with keys an values.  Sounds like you'd rather use something like [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: See [superluminary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473984/3499424) for a compelling contextual reason to prefer `Record` over an index signature. When the set of keys is finite _and_ you want to use it in more than one place (e.g. constraining a string parameter in addition to associating with typed data), `Record` allows you to use a set of keys defined independently.

Comment: the syntax `{ [k: T]: V }` can either indicate the index signature, if `T` is a `string`, `number` `symbol`, or a mapped type when `T` is an expression containing a generic parameter that is assigned an union of constant values. The main difference is that in the first case you are not required to provide a property for each possible value of type `T`, but you will get a constraint that if you have a property it has to be of value `V`, in the second case you get a set of required properties. Arguably only the latter is a `Record` so using `Record<string,...>` would be improper.

Answer (score 294):

A `Record` lets you create a new type from a Union. The values in the Union are used as attributes of the new type.

For example, say I have a Union like this:

```
type CatNames = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
```

Now I want to create an object that contains information about all the cats, I can create a new type using the values in the `CatNames` union as keys.

```
type CatList = Record<CatNames, {age: number}>
```

If I want to satisfy this `CatList`, I must create an object like this:

```
const cats: CatList = {
  miffy: { age:99 },
  boris: { age:16 },
  mordred: { age:600 }
}
```

You get very strong type safety:

- If I forget a cat, I get an error.
- If I add a cat that's not allowed, I get an error.
- If I later change `CatNames`, I get an error. This is especially useful because `CatNames` is likely imported from another file, and likely used in many places.

### Real-world React example.

I used this recently to create a `Status` component. The component would receive a `status` prop, and then render an icon. I've simplified the code quite a lot here for illustrative purposes

I had a union like this:

```
type Statuses = "failed" | "complete";
```

I used this to create an object like this:

```
const icons: Record<
  Statuses,
  { iconType: IconTypes; iconColor: IconColors }
> = {
  failed: {
    iconType: "warning",
    iconColor: "red"
  },
  complete: {
    iconType: "check",
    iconColor: "green"
  };
```

I could then render by destructuring an element from the object into props, like so:

```
const Status = ({status}) => <Icon {...icons[status]} />
```

If the `Statuses` union is later extended or changed, I know my Status component will fail to compile and I'll get an error that I can fix immediately. This allows me to add additional error states to the app.

Note that the actual app had dozens of error states that were referenced in multiple places, so this type safety was extremely useful.

Comment: I assume most of the time `type Statuses` lives in typings NOT defined by you? Otherwise I can see something like an interface with an enum being a better fit right?

Comment: Hi @victorio, I'm not sure how an enum would solve the problem, you don't get an error in an enum if you miss a key. It's just a mapping between keys and values.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Coming from C# we do not have clever ways to do that. The closest thing would be a dictionary of `Dictionary<enum, additional_metadata>`. The Record type is a great way to represent that enum + metadata pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to initialize a record that has several keys mapped to a single value? Let's say I have 10 different statuses but in the UI all of them should be shown with a warning icon. If I go with record type, I'll have to duplicate the same 10 times, which I would be able to avoid if I use something like a switch statement.

Comment: Well, but `const bla: CatNames = "miffy";` works. TS describes the `|` as a union type, so only *one* is needed, but the record needs all. Very confusing. JS with TS is still a mess.

Comment: @Jennifer Kiesel in your case you you have a cost not a type, so they are different object.

Comment: @JenniferKiesel You are correct, CatNames is a union type which means it can have any value in the list. If we generate a Record from it, this means we can make an object that is guaranteed to have a key for each element in the union. This is useful when accessing an object using square braces because you can guarantee that there's a property in the object to match every valid value of the string. It can be confusing to start with, but it's not messy.

Comment: "If I forget a cat, I get an error." Is this really true, do you have to enumerate all possible values of K when instantiating a `record<K,V>`? How would that event work when K is of type `string`?

Answer (score 9):

There is now a slightly longer documentation of the Record type:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Quoting that:

> Record<Keys, Type>
> Released:
> 2.1

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property
> values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type
> to another type.

```
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}
 
type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
 
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
  miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
  boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
  mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};
 
cats.boris;
 
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo>
```

Answer (score 4):

simple example of using Record :

let say we have the following object and we want to define an object type for it.

```js
const networkConfig = {
 4: {
    name: "rinkeby",
    ethUsdPriceFeed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e",
  }
}
```

So the type will be like the following one using Record :

```js
type networkConfigType = Record<number, {
    name: string;
    ethUsdPriceFeed: string;
}>;
```

Comment: what difference between

type networkConfigType = {
    [key: number]: {
name: string;
    ethUsdPriceFeed: string;
}
};

Comment: Both code snippets define the same type for an object with numeric keys and a specific structure. Your suggestion is a more explicit way to define it, while mine uses the Record utility type for brevity. Functionally, they are equivalent.