# Object Type Application in Definitely Typed file

Tags: javascript, types, intellisense, jsdoc, .d.ts

Is it possible to create an object type application expression in a definitely typed file?

In normal JSDoc you can define it using way shown below:

```
/* @type {Object.<string, number>} */
var x = {
  "0": 0,
  "1": 1
};
```

But the same thing doesn't get parsed in a `.d.ts` file (the variable is of type `any`).

```
const x: Object.<string, number>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an indexer or the builtin `Record` type:

```
const x: {[key: string]: number};
const x: Record<string, number>;
```

They would both do the same thing.

For more on the Record type: [What is the Record type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Would it also be possible to be able to keep the Object signature (intellisense doesn't treat `x` as an `Object` so I don't get methods `hasOwnProperty`).