# Is it possible in TypeScript to constrain a string indexer to the names and types of the sibling properties?

Tags: typescript

## The Context

In TypeScript, a string indexer can be declared like this:

```
class MyClass {
   prop1: CustomType1;
   prop2: CustomType2;
   [key: string]: any // <--- indexer
}
```

## The Question

Is it possible to declare the indexer with the following characteristics *without* having to explicitly declare each name and type on the signature?

- The key is constrained to the property names (e.g: 'prop1' | 'prop2')
- The type is constrained to the property types (e.g.: CustomType1 | CustomType2).

For example, can something like the following pseudo-code be achieved?

```
class MyClass {
   prop1: CustomType1;
   prop2: CustomType2;
   [key: MYCLASS PROP NAMES]: MYCLASS PROP TYPES // <--- pseudo-code 
}
```

Thanks for any input

Comment: The type `{prop1: CustomType1, prop2: CustomType2}` already constrains the keys to `"prop1"|"prop2"` and the values at those keys to `CustomType1 | CustomType2`, without the need for any kind of index signature.  For what purpose would you like such an indexer... I mean, what do you think you can do with an index signature that you can't do with just `{prop1: CustomType1, prop2: CustomType2}`?

Comment: @jcalz - I have some reusable code paths, that use something like the following:

`this.myClassInstance[fieldName] = fieldValue`

To allow this, I need to add an indexer. I have been looking at the [Advanced Types TypeScript Documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), and in particular the `keyof` keyword.  It looks like this should be able to be leveraged somehow, but I couldn't quite figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Like [this](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHCARmQG9kExyAuZbKUAc2QF8BuAKFEixEKDNnzEyAJmq0wkpi3Zc+CADZxMmZAFkiqdZuq9kJ5CSg4SjNFlyFSFPqbMWS8m2PtSnphDhAs6HQ4UAAU5pbWonYSFAA0Lpbu0eIOkgCURs7OYAAWwJgAdBFWyAC8iVY+2ch5BcWu0hUlktVcvJy8ahpaAIIgOHnQ+j1Zpnh6BpgAkgFgcCBITLojmm1+c1BBuGETqzNzC0s6kz2ZVMY1tflFe1Oz2EcoFXc9D-OLEG2dzngQeTgACYAHgA0sgIAAPSAgQFaADWECIOBgJ32AD5QjBgBBVICAHJwP5MUEJbG4wEANTgqnQEGWp00AG1QQBdc6XGp1W6Mg6PT5M8l4wl-VnlZBCqk0unfDq8IA)?  You don't need to modify `MyClass`; you need to properly type `fieldName` and `fieldValue`.

Comment: @jcalz - OK, interesting. If I constrain fieldName and fieldValue to keyof and types of MyClass, then I don't need to define an indexer on MyClass. Your typescript-play link was a big help. If you want to put your comment as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add some type definitions so this code compiles:

```
interface CustomType1 { ct1: string };
interface CustomType2 { ct2: string };
```

As I mentioned in the comments, there should be no need to add an indexer to your type, because it already has the behavior that you want from it.  So the type

```
type MyType = { 
   prop1: CustomType1,
   prop2: CustomType2
}
```

already has keys `"prop1" | "prop2"`:

```
type KeysOfMyType = keyof MyType; // "prop1" | "prop2"
```

and has values at those keys of `CustomType1 | CustomType2`:

```
type ValuesOfMyType = MyType[KeysOfMyType]; // CustomType1 | CustomType2
```

The closest thing to an index signature that you could use would be a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like [`Record<K, V>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript):

```
type BlurredMyType = Record<KeysOfMyType, ValuesOfMyType>;
// type BlurredMyType = { 
//   prop1: CustomType1 | CustomType2; 
//   prop2: CustomType1 | CustomType2;
// }
```

But such a type is "blurred" in the sense that you can no longer tell which property type goes with which key.  Still, any value of type `MyType` should be assignable to a variable of type `BlurredMyType`, since "blurring" produces a supertype:

```
declare const myType: MyType;
const blurred: BlurredMyType = myType; // okay, no error
```

So if you absolutely need something like this, you can define `Blur<T>` as

```
type Blur<T> = Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]>;
```

but using a `T` as a `Blur<T>` loses some specificity on property reads, and loses some type safety on property writes:

```
declare const customType2: CustomType2;
blurred.prop1 = customType2; // no error, but now myType.prop1 is wrong
```

---

Instead of trying to widen or alter your class to include an index signature, it's more reasonable to properly constrain possible key/value types when using indexed access to the type.  That is, use types like `K extends keyof MyClass` and `MyClass[K]` to assure the compiler that you are correctly accessing `MyClass`.  Here is an example with a method that does this, as well as an unsafe method that uses the blurred type:

```
class MyClass {
  prop1: CustomType1;
  prop2: CustomType2;
  constructor(prop1: CustomType1, prop2: CustomType2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
  }
}

class AnotherClass {
  myClassInstance: MyClass;
  constructor(myClassInstance: MyClass) {
    this.myClassInstance = myClassInstance;
  }
  // generic method, fieldName and fieldValue are constrained
  method<K extends keyof MyClass>(fieldName: K, fieldValue: MyClass[K]) {
    this.myClassInstance[fieldName] = fieldValue;
  }

  // this works too but is not safe
  unsafeMethod(fieldName: keyof MyClass, fieldValue: MyClass[keyof MyClass]) {
      const myBlurredClassInstance: Blur<MyClass> = this.myClassInstance;
      myBlurredClassInstance[fieldName] = fieldValue;
  }
}


const ac = new AnotherClass(new MyClass({ct1: "a"}, {ct2: "b"}));
ac.method("prop1", {ct1: "okay"}); // okay
ac.method("prop2", {ct1: "whoops"}); // error
ac.unsafeMethod("prop1", {ct1: "okay"}); // okay
ac.unsafeMethod("prop2", {ct1: "whoops"}); // no error!
```

As you can see, the `method()` call complains if you pass a value and a key that don't match, while the `unsafeMethod()` call does not.  You do need to be somewhat careful, even with the "safe" method:

```
ac.method(Math.random()<0.5 ? "prop1" : "prop2", {ct1: "whoops"}); // no error!
```

In this case the type of `K` is inferred to be `"prop1" | "prop2"` which is unsafe for property writes.  It's just the way it is.

---

In any case, you probably don't need anything like an index signature; you just need to use properly constrained types for indexed access.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to all code in Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-PRAwfKCYLXRwHjYCAQGgYAEFxCB5xwZZThgYAIGqZYADk4DwFBr2WZBCOI5YqlqKj9SxFg4FAFYTxw0c8MOPkAA9IBAZZw1VeI8y-a5WzokjyMopg-AIoiSMYuo7wfDpemAxw5wXG0IIvK8bwgNoZLIii+nWMzVIgJDkLSMDwz9XYonDXBeW9Mkw2QXdmDgGAIEcdBsX8iANG4vDpOU8z5OQMSAIfJT6Js9SvxVWJxMAw8tOHEcGxxPE6WpeCjP-EUJMPcV9Ec-SssM39jNnSFCqpFYSoapBTOiuTLP0azzlsxx10zViyUQdZ0IDHccD3KAH1bSaEq-VsqDoCx0jgdJuFOVa5CYdJyS2gcBzuRB9Ii5ZW0yEN0h2tb9vZTkjtZR6iF4M7KNwy7ruhW7qHujI-R4sxMGe5AHn5XZ3oQG1gswULwq+q6-j+3b1tesGHle6HYZCgLEZ477e1RgH0iBnAQcxtI3UhqAAEJSg+i7Ww0OB5xtKBqPwVsB32AAGG0AFZkAAfkKG7kH24m7vofbycp7gTvB6neVphnSiAA)

---

Comment: fantastic answer! This not only answered my question, but also gave me some new insights into some of the more advanced aspects of TypeScript. Many thanks!