# How can I specify an array type with custom properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example, if I am attaching additional data (in the form of key-value pairs, where the keys are strings) to an array instance, how can I extend the type of this instance of an array to allow for this additional data?

```js
const associativeArray: string[] & Record<string, string> = ['some', 'array', 'data']
/*
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] & Record<string, string>'.
  Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'never[]'.ts(2322)
*/

associativeArray.customKey = 'customValue'
```

Comment: You could type it `[...] as any` for the initial assignment.

Comment: This seems dangerous. Are the keys of the key-value pairs known at compile time? Do you want those keys to show up in the `length` property, and can you guarantee that array methods like `push` wouldn't show up as keys?

Comment: As in JavaScript, `associativeArray.customKey = 'customValue'` would not affect the `length`, so I would not want the custom keys to affect the array length. I can also guarantee that array methods wouldn't get overridden, but would that guarantee be possible in TypeScript as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extend array types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#extending-expressions) since Typescript 1.6.

```js
class MyArray extends Array<string> {
  customKey?: string;
}
```

However, doing so with arbitrary string keys is probably a bad idea, because doing so with numeric strings will still affect Array behavior like `length`, and because you can overwrite Array properties and methods in Javascript and Typescript both. If you allow arbitrary string keys, you will probably lose many of the benefits of typing your object.

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(foo.length);                        // 3
foo.arbitraryString = "arbitrary";
console.log(foo.length);                        // 3
foo["anotherArbitraryString"] = "arbitrary";
console.log(foo.length);                        // 3
foo["3"] = "d";
console.log(foo.length);                        // 4
foo["push"] = () => console.log("Oops.");
foo.push("e");                                  // Oops.
```

[[Fiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/ox387js5/)

And in any case, it is [equivalent and more idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51937036/1426891) to use `[key: string]: string` as a property than a `Record<string, string>`.