# Is it possible to represent a type of object that must only have single key from a union of string literals?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a CapabilitySet that represents grants for a number of features. Each key is a capability/feature name, where most values are an 'Enablement', but a few are a 'Limitation` that regulates the feature's usage:

```
type CapabilityEnablementName = 'feature_toggled_by_enablement' // | etc...
type CapabilityLimitationName = 'feature_toggled_by_limit' // | etc...

type CapabilityName = CapabilityEnablementName & CapabilityLimitationName

type CapabilityEnablement = { enabled: boolean }
type CapabilityLimitation = { infinite: boolean; max: number | null }
```

**Can I specify that `max` is `null` when `infinite` is `true`?**

From this, I'd also like to say a single Capability is an object with a CapabilityName that is either a CapabilityEnablement or CapabilityLimitation based on a given CapabilityName.

The CapabilitySet would use mapped types to generate something like:

```
type Capability<C extends CapabilityName> = C extends CapabilityLimitationName
   ? { [C]: CapabilityLimitation }
   : { [C]: CapabilityEnablement } 

type CapabilitySet = {
   [K in CapabilityName]: Capability;
}
```

**Is this possible with unions of string literals?**  It seems that TS won't allow the key to be a string literal, perhaps because a union may not be strictly strings?

I currently have the keys explicitly defined in a full CapabilitySet, which seems better for code completion and typedoc, but I'm curious about what's possible if I want this level of granularity.

Comment: `type CapabilityName = CapabilityEnablementName & CapabilityLimitationName` are you using `&` on purpose here?  That's an intersection, not a union, and from the code in the example, it will evaluate to `never`.

Comment: And are you just looking for `Record<C, ...>` instead of `{[C]: ...}` ?  See [What is the `Record` type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript)

Comment: This kind of looks like multiple questions..."Can I specify that max is null when infinite is true?"  `type CapabilityLimitation = { infinite: true; max: null } | { infinite: false; max: number }`.  Although do note that `Infinity` is a `number` so you might not need a separate field

Comment: It is two questions, but the former is less important. For that case Infinity is not a possible value in JSON (I suppose I could extend the JSONObject type from type-fest).

Comment: CapabilityName is meant to be a union, not an intersection.

If I used Record, could I still achieve the desired result be checked that C is in one union or the other?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghmOAjAlgGxaAogO2WiAWwh2ADk5ioBeKAIgDMI5gBXAJwgH1gB7Ac34EAJlyQguJfERLA6AbigB6JVAA+UCMADGAOn0BYAFChIsBMnSYQAGRSFMLFLxwUqtRszaceAoRFFxLgwHOUUVdU0dfV1jY1NoeERUDFA3aFoky1SQXGliUnTIrJTrO1CnF3T5OJNwRItS7DwkAgLgGigAb00WkQAuKCReXgI4HCgAXxq6sxKrUHLHYGcJ6mMoSJ6UHAYdzAhB4HZWCEVCOAAPQZxWNDQpja2oHb2cA8GGODQAZzOoC7XKC3QhICDsKYzeL1czJBYgADKWk6XSeAG0ANIvCbzHLpAC6gyxEEuwBIwh+sOy1jyrRkhUoECemwA-FSmrk+vTgMyoETNKTyZTcWV7MtVkU2SLFmLgJUJjcIAA3cHGabGIA) what you want?  Without use cases or an [mcve] it's hard to know if I understand what you want.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple questions, you should consider posting them separately.

Comment: That is what I was looking for.