# typing svg element react in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having issues typing the following.

The issue is with the `TeamIcon`.

My object is defined as follows.

```
import TeamIcon from './components/icons/TeamIcon';

export const teamObject: Record<
  string,
  Record<string, string | React.ReactSVGElement>
> = {
  team: {
    icon: TeamIcon,
    color: '#B2649B',
  }
}
```

My `TeamIcon` looks like this:

```
export default (props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => (
  <svg width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 18" {...props}>
    <path
      fill="currentColor"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="..."
    />
  </svg>
);
```

Then the following error is being displayed:

> JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.

```
const Icon = currentTeam.icon;

<Icon
  width="29px"
  height="29px"
  style={{ color: currentTeam.color }}
/>
```

Does anyone know how to type this correctly?

Comment: Can you put this up in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html as a minimal example and put the link here?

Comment: sure, although could be tricky as it's react. Leave it with me

Comment: [React works fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=9#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoAHgEk0IA7OAegD4g)

Comment: ah, in the meantime I have got this working for you - https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dewdney-tvme5  you can see the errors if you hover over the red and yellow underlined code. Let me know if that works, otherwise can add something to this ts playground.Tbh the code sandbox is showing the exact same error

Comment: That works! But why are are you `Record` here exactly?

Comment: why am I using `Record`? Not sure if that is what your question means. Presume that is what you are asking

Comment: Yes. You use it twice in your type for `teamObject`. [`Record` takes a union of strings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) as property names and a type, and sets the types of all those property names to that type. That isn't what you want when you have properties with very different types that you can easily know in advance.

Comment: thanks for this, and thanks for your answer. So `Record` should be used for more straight forward objects?

Comment: I've written a ton of typescript and never actually had a use for `Record`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript) has some great info on it.

Comment: woah, I have only used it when working with objects  but just the way I learned. Will read through that answer

Comment: Yeah, you probably want to use `interface` instead for typing objects. Only go beyond that when you need to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TeamIcon` isn't a type here, it's the name of local variable, that has value of a React functional component.

So I think you want something like this, which is the type of a React functional component, with props of your choosing.

```
icon: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>
```

A full example would be something like:

```
interface TeamObject {
  team: {
    icon: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>,
    color: string,
  }
}

const teamObject: TeamObject = {
  team: {
    icon: TeamIcon,
    color: "#B2649B"
  }
};
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mclean-6k37q)

---

You'll note that I got rid of this:

```
Record<
  string,
  Record<string, string | React.ReactSVGElement>
>
```

I'm not really sure what the goal of that was, but you clearly have two properties with very different types. You have `icon` which is a function that returns `React.ReactNode` and you have `color` which is a string. So you should be typing those explicitly.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, but this solution won't resolve anything. The only difference is that the icon is coming from within `node_modules`. I'm guessing something is wrong with my TSConfig such that the typings aren't being picked up?