# Typescript: property key based on type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to define a property name based on the generic type passed?

```
type Foo<T> = {
  // magic goes here
  someProp: boolean
};

enum MyEnum {
  red = 'red',
  blue= 'blue',
}

const d: Foo<MyEnum.blue> = null;
d.someProp
d.blue // Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'Foo<MyEnum.blue>'.ts(2339)
```

Been looking all over the docs, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you just looking for something like [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) as in [this](https://tsplay.dev/mplQXm)?

Comment: Exactly that @jcalz, thank you!. is there a way to do it with an interface instead of a type?

Comment: No, an interface must have statically known keys.  You can write `interface XYZ extends Foo<MyEnum.blue> {}` but you cannot write `interface XYZ<T extends PropertyKey> extends Foo<T> {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to generate an object type on the fly given the types of its keys and associated values.  For example, the type `{[P in "x" | "y"]: [P]}` produces the type `{x: ["x"], y: ["y"]}`. For the case where the value type does not depend on the key, you can use the built in [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) utility type, described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51937036/2887218).  So `Record<"x" | "y", number>` is equivalent to `{x: number, y: number}`.

In your case, you want `Foo<T>` to have the key `T`, which means we need to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to just keylike types (that is `string | number | symbol`, or you can use the  [built in `PropertyKey` alias](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/970554733a3578cd854606ebcb316f291632b118/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L105)).  In such cases, `K` is a more conventional parameter name than `T`.  Let me start over:

You want `Foo<K extends PropertyKey>` to have `K` as a key. I'm not sure what value type you want at that key; for now I'll just use [`any`, the ultimate ‍♂️ type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  And you walso want `Foo<K>` to have a `boolean` property at the `"someProp"` key.  So it should be *both* `Record<K, any>`, *and* a `{someProp: boolean}`.  That implies you want it to be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of those:

```
type Foo<K extends PropertyKey> = {
  someProp: boolean
} & Record<K, any>
```

And you can verify that this works:

```
const d: Foo<MyEnum.blue> = {
  blue: 123,
  someProp: true
}
```

Note that you cannot make `Foo` an `interface`.  In both `class` and `interface` types, the compiler needs to know the keys statically, in advance of usage:

```
interface Oops<K extends PropertyKey>
  extends Foo<K> { } // error!
// -----> ~~~~~~
// An interface can only extend an object type or 
// intersection of object types with statically known members.
```

For a particular specification of `K`, though, you can make an interface:

```
interface FooBlue extends Foo<MyEnum.blue> { } // okay

const e: FooBlue = {
  someProp: true,
  blue: new Date()
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAaShAHsCA7AJgZygAUAnOSE0ZCEAPigF4oBvAKCinzgFsJTyAXFABGCADYQAhtlYBfKADIoAJQgBjOCVwoANFGl1WrHAFduUALIgAotjMt2UEhFyMoAcme53Ox8LEm0Ezu-oE+ckYa2PjAULhC8EhWtmYAdKEQ9ExsHBlCAIwATADMvhxcvPxgQsAkgRGsAJbYWCQAZpJq0ADy5PgoaJg4BMRkFFQ0tI4YWHiEiSj0zFDyAPSraCRkJACErOtQALTHx-QAfheX+xsAgthQza0dXVBq0lBw2GIgg7Ou73BhAArdSxUCQD4kKDXB4tCAkfCgxqfD5tD7A0FQcEQQgAd0awAAFpxgJJgI03mJvlAANbYOC4+68bjCeH4VJGR7w57QRIAIQC0Bmw3mCEQyTs3HSgqWKygBzgNMkIEinxiaASCAFgTcOU4PD4YxqdQgZREgqE2AguKgABEyRAABQASgiQA)