# How to Enforce field to be in object typescript

Tags: typescript

I have to create a type that has one required property and the rest can be anything.
For example I want to have all objects that have _id: string

```
{_id: "123"} // will work
{a: 1} // wont work because doesnt have _id field 
{_id:"sadad", a:1} // will work
```

How can I do it with typesccript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly inform the type there is a key with `_id` and after that, it can be any object key-value pair `Record<string, unknown>`

```js
type ObjectType = { _id: string } & Record<string, unknown>;

const a: ObjectType = { _id: "123" }; // will work
const b: ObjectType = { a: 1 }; // Property '_id' is missing in type
const c: ObjectType = { _id: "sadad", a: 1 }; // will work
```

---

P.S. Reference for RecordKey

[What is the Record type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript)