# Typescript - How to create a type with the same properties as an interface, but with different property types

Tags: typescript, types

I'm making a query builder. I have data models that look like this:

```
export interface SalesOrder {
  id: number
  customerName: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

In my query builder, I want to have the `columns` look something like this:

```
{
  id: 'salesOrder.id',
  customerName: 'customer.name',
  date: 'salesOrder.date',
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can type the `Columns` object generically so that it will have all the keys from the model, but all of the types will be a string. So then I would be able to declare it like `const columns: Columns<SalesOrder>` and it would understand that the object must have all the same keys as in the `SalesOrder` model, but with all the values being `string`.

I tried this:

```
export interface Columns<T> {
  [alias: keyof T]: string;
}
```

But it complains about the `keyof T` part, saying "An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end of that error message should have been:

> Consider using a mapped object type instead.

[See the documentation on mapped types.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

Here's what that means:

```
export type Columns<T> = {
  [alias in keyof T]: string;
}
```

It needs to be a `type`, because this is actually a mapped type. It walks all possibilities of `keyof T` and evaluates each member of that union individually. This isn't really supported in interfaces.

And `[key: MyType]` is an index signature. It says that for any `MyType` there is a value of a consistent type. Where `[key in MyType]` define the keys of a mapped type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZUwBtgBnAeSgBM04BvAWACg5EqAuOJAVwFsAjNM1bZupGBF5oAcpimdxUZAHMA3MLhVMqTgBFtwdUwC+zZqEiw4MAJ5g8AYQhE+SUgB4AKgD44AXnoNAG1iBExSRCQ4AGtgGwh0OE8AXQUYJSQ1ZlMmZmwIN3hUcU4nF143d0ISCmo0XwDGFjZOAHJSYjJKGigAOgQqVoAaDVFxSRk5YDaxiSk+pCnhjS0dOHbO2p7e1eBlkyA)

---

Alternatively, you could try the `Record` type.

```
export type Columns<T> = Record<keyof T, string>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZUwBtgBnAeSgBM04BvAWACg5EqAuOJAVwFsAjNM1bZupGBF5oAcpimdxUZAHMA3MLhVMqTgBFtwdUwC+zZqEiw4MAJ5g8AYQhE+SUgB4AKgD44AXjgAJWBsaCp3AGtgGwh0OE8AGjhFFW8zJlC3eFRxTicXXjd3QhIKajRfAMYWNk4AclJiMkoaKAA6BCo6hI1RcUkZOWB6vokpdqQh7o0tHTgGprLWttngaZMgA)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is any effective difference between the two solutions? Or is it basically up to whatever my semantic preference is?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that [the definition of Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript) is `type Record<K extends string, T> = { [P in K]: T }` so I think they are completely equivalent.