# using a array to access state object on condition using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following object with an extended state object, I made an array of values that I want to check using a for of loop and check the state object's current value, issue is I cannot make the array value compatible with state object key, how to make them fit telling typescript that the value is a compatible key for the state object ?

```js
const inicialState = {
  a: true
  b: true
  c: false
  d: true
  e: true
};

const [type, setType] = useState < typeof inicialState > (inicialState);

const requirments = ['a', 'n', 'c'];
for (const value of requirments) {
  if (!type[value] /* Cannot acces object key */ ) {
    console.log('false')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the idea is that your `requirements` array is dynamic (we cannot guarantee that everything in that array is a key of `type`), so typescript is just warning you (or throwing error if you in strict mode) about that. A work around is to use `Object.keys` to check if a string exists in an object key:
Update: at this point typescript still cannot infer that the `value` here is a `keyof` `inicialState` so we just kinda have to help it a little bit

```
if (Object.keys(type).includes(value)) {
  console.log(type[value as keyof typeof inicialState]);
}
```

Another way is to annotate the `type` to be an object with that could have any string for it keys:

```
const inicialState: Record<string, boolean> = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: false,
    d: true,
    e: true
};
```

Comment: nice approach. I just solved the issue I will answer as well with different approach, you can see my approach you might like it.

Comment: I want to access the values so object.keys in your answer won't work !!! there is a major issue with your answer, please consider editing.

Comment: I just updated it. At this point I would consider going with the 2nd approach that I had in the comment unless you want to be really strict with your typing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you can solve this problem.

Your `requirements` array is inferred as a `string[]`, but what you want it to actually represent is "an array of the possible keys in `inicialState`; you can use `keyof` and `typeof` to help here:

```
const requirments: (keyof typeof inicialState)[] = ['a', 'n', 'c'];
```

However, now you'll be warned that `n` isn't a valid key (which it isn't!) - so you either need to give `n` an initial value:

```
const inicialState: InicialState = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: true,
  n: undefined,
};
```

Or better still, if your set of keys is fixed, then you should create a type / interface that describes the `inicialState`:

```
interface InicialState {
  a: boolean;
  b: boolean;
  c: boolean;
  d: boolean;
  e: boolean;
  n?: boolean;
};

const inicialState: InicialState = {
  // ...
};

const requirments: (keyof InicialState)[] = ['a', 'n', 'c'];
```

And if the set of keys is *not* fixed then you can use `Record<string, boolean>`:

```
const inicialState: Record<string, boolean> = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: true,
};
```

Comment: what is this Record thing haven't see it yet ? could you explain.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

```js
type ObjectKey = keyof typeof type;

const requirments = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as ObjectKey[];

for (const value of requirments) {
  if (!type[value]) {
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```