# Pass map<string,string> as an input to an angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass an input value when reusing a component, the problem is that it will be a "hardcoded" map of strings and I am unsure how to pass that:

```
<continue-p
  [additionalInfo]="{ "myString": "string", "myNumber": "4" }">
  <p>
    Paragraph
  </p>
</continue-p>
```

and the input field looks like this:

```
@Input()
  additionalInfo?: Map<string, string>;
```

PS I am not sure if there is a better structure for passing such information to components, please recommend.

Comment: It should be `Record<string, string>`. [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) are totally different.

Comment: @caTS How would I pass that? Would it support multiple entries?

Comment: `Record<string, string>` is (structurally) equivalent to `{ [key: string]: string }`. So yes, it would support multiple entries. You can read this type as "a type where all of its keys are strings and all of its values are strings".

Comment: This seems to work, you can post your answer if you want me to pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) are different than objects and have their own type `Map<K, V>`. Since you are using a plain object, you can use [`Record<K, V>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript) instead.

`Record<string, string>` is a way to represent `{ [key: string]; string] }`, or an object whose keys are strings and values are strings.

So it'd be as simple as changing `Map` to `Record` in your code:

```
additionalInfo?: Record<string, string>;
```