# How to declare an object filled with arrays?I

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a variable that is an object filled with arrays for example:

```js
let obj = {
    "page1"     : [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
    "page2"     : [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
    "dsfsfffsfs": [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ]
}
```

How can I declare that as an interface in typescript?

Comment: How _variadic_ are those `"page1"` and `"page2"` property-keys?

Comment: they can be anything like fgsdgkfsdgn or snfdfggsggg

Comment: Your last key doesn't contain an array?

Comment: O sorry it's an array.

Comment: I guess for your object, it's `Record<string, number[]>`. [What is a Record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type)

Comment: I have another question. I changed the format of the variable. It's now an object with arrays of objects. How do we represent that? See question

Answer (score 2):

If you will always have `number` elements in your arrays, you can type it using the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```ts
Record<string, number[]>
```

where the keys are `string`s and the values are `number[]` (arrays of numbers) like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVgLggJRAYygJwCYB4DOYmAlgHYDmANBKQK4C2MImA2gLoB8EAvBAN4AoCBAAOAQ3IgAjEhYQp1AEzUAzBDaUhoiSEWyIyiCuoAWdZuHZ8AMxvXbt-QoOrzAgL4BuAUA)

```ts
let obj: Record<string, number[]> = {
  page1: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  page2: [ 2, 3, 4 ],
  dsfsfffsfs: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
};
```

---

However, you can also create your own type utility that allows you to provide a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) for the array elements:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2DAZgQQE7YIYgA8AKgHxQC8UASigPbYAmhAzsNgJYB2A5gDRRiAbQC6pANwAoSQHoZggBbQWeALbQ8LKAG8oADwBcULgFdVcCNnFQQR0+cvWAvpNCQoAYTzZgEFhzwuDzoGRm48Xy0qWmRQwgByPXioAB8oeJB4gXsLbAlpABsIYCg6RCN4JFQMHHwiLx8-AKCQpnDI8iptSSgoMDweCABGIyEdQyghgVsoACYnAW0J2emjAFYnKBE+Hr6BiFnR8aMpmyN5xeXVqA2tnd7GFnQn9Gfno6WT64vjuevb7aSJxSIA)

```ts
type ObjectOfArray<T> = Record<string, T[]>;

// The same as { x: number; y: number; }
type CartesianCoordinates = Record<'x' | 'y', number>;

let obj: ObjectOfArray<CartesianCoordinates> = {
  page1: [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
  page2: [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
  dsfsfffsfs: [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
};
```

---

And if the arrays should always have exactly 2 elements, then you can use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type to indicate that:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJ2BAzgSzgOxgexwgEzUzmRSgF4oAlCAY3wIB4ByADxagB8oWQWANFEwBXALYAjCAgB8AbgBQCgDYRgUHBIBWALhr1GTFMATEA5kIDa8JKgzY8hYqVRCbZe7kbOyAXRmUUADeClBQYHBmEACMepbBbHrRQiB6AEwAvkJBiVBpKXoArBlQvgKh4ZEQaXEJSQV5WXV5DcWl5WEEKABmPd29vbU59VCpjdm5+aNFJWUKGYpAA)

```ts
type CartesianCoordinates = Record<'x' | 'y', number>;

let obj: Record<string, [CartesianCoordinates, CartesianCoordinates]> = {
  page1: [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
  page2: [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
  dsfsfffsfs: [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want interface. One way to do it is like this.

```
interface xx {
    x : number,
    y : number,
}
interface yy {
    "page1" : xx[],
    "page2" : xx[],
    "dsfsfffsfs" : xx[]
}
```