# how to type for object of object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to type for following data. I have to type for progress object

```
const progress = {
   "1": {
      topic: [1,3,4],
      assessment: [1,2,4,],
   },
   "2": {
      topic: [1,3,4],
      assessment: [1,2,4,],
   },
   ....
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) yet?

Comment: i haven't completed that yet. Event i don't have time to read that now

Comment: About *I don't have time to read that now* [Specifically saying that your needs are urgent or that you need an answer ASAP implies that your time is more valuable than the time of other people asking questions, or of the people answering questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean that..thanks for your valuable time.  I have a tight deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in type - [Record<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type)

```
type Obj = Record<string, {topic: number[], assessment: number[]}>
```