# Make list of map in typescript which is correspond to java List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, typescript, type-conversion, fetch

I am having a function with **List<Map<String, String>>** as argument type in java.
I want to make a fetch call from Typescript file. For that I need to define a variable whose type should be correspond to **List<Map<String, String>>**.

Since typescript does not have inbuilt type as list then how can we define List<Map<String, String>> in **Typescript** ??

For the reference -
The java function receive input as below

```
  [
   {
    xyz: 'Test',
    abc: 'Count',
   },
   {
    xyz: 'Test',
    abc: 'Latency',
   },
  ]
```

**How can I receive this List<Map<String, String>>  in typescript** ??

Comment: That's an `Array<{xyz: string, abc: string}>` with no conversion necessary, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJXqRN).  Or maybe an `Array<{[k: string]: string}>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj1ZkW).  You don't need `Map`, probably. ... but what is the use case? What do you intend to *do* with a variable of this type?

Comment: I want to have a list of map for storing different maps value in list and throw fetch call at once

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what "throw fetch call at once" means.  Ideally you'd [edit] the question to show your use case as code, or at least pseudocode.

Comment: I'm assuming that because you're familiar with Java, you wouldn't be asking for `Map` if you had `xyz` and `abc` as known keys.  So I'd suggest `Array<{[k: string]: string}>`. Then you can use built-in JS object/array manipulation methods, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nar1pm).   If that works for you I could write up an answer, although @caTS's answer is essentially correct and maybe could just be edited to show uses, if that's what you're doing.  Anyway, let me know if you need anything further here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting an array. Arrays can be represented with the built-in generic:

```
Array<T>
```

or using `[]` (similarly to Java):

```
T[]
```

The objects inside the array are normal objects, with string keys mapping to string values. This can be represented with a [Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript):

```
Record<string, string>
```

So you should get either:

```
Record<string, string>[]
```

or

```
Array<Record<string, string>>
```

as the type.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Won't Array<Map<string, string>> work the similar ?

Comment: `Map<string, string>` can store the same basic information as `{[k: string]: string}`/`Record<string, string>`, but they are different data structures.  Unless you have some actual defined use case where `Map` is necessary, I'd stick with `{[k: string]: string}`/`Record<string, string>` because that's the form the data arrives in. Otherwise you'd have to transform back and forth in order to communicate with your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use the type `{[key: string]: string}[]`.
For example, this code is working on my side:

```
let foo: {[key: string]: string}[] = [];
foo = [
  {
   xyz: 'Test',
   abc: 'Count',
  },
  {
   xyz: 'Test',
   abc: 'Latency',
  },
 ];
console.log(foo);
```