# Use similar, derived property names in multiple Typescript interfaces or create new interfaces based on interface property names

Tags: typescript, interface

I am searching for a solution how to create two interfaces that have somewhat similar named properties like this:

```ts
interface Int1 {
  propOne: string;
  propTwo?: number;
  propThree?: Date;
}

interface Int2 {
  propOneIndex: number;
  propTwoIndex?: number;
  propThreeIndex?: number;
}
```

You can see that the properties' names in `Int2` are extended from `Int1` with the postfix "Index". Is there a way to approach this?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68839147/5539598), where someone uses an enum and [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) but that requires Typescript version ^4.1 which I don't have. I thought there might be a simpler solution as I expect this to be a common use case.

Comment: You can only do this with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), new in TS 4.1. Otherwise you have to maintain it manually.

Comment: It *is* a common use case, which is why template literal types and key remapping were introduced in TypeScript 4.1.  Generally speaking, TypeScript is under active development and changes frequently enough that any dependency you have on a previous version of TypeScript will become increasingly burdensome for you.  My only advice here is to figure out how to upgrade.